# awk parsing with fixed number of fields

Tags: bash, awk

Looking for solution to parse with awk records, where, within can be also `/n` characters. The records are delimited with `|`. Problem is that to determine new line can be done when reached certain number of fields. How this can be done in awk?

Example:

```
2013-03-24 15:49:40.575175 EST|aaa|tsi|p1753|th2056569632|172.30.10.212|56809|2013-03-24 15:49:32 AFT|10354453|con2326|cmd7|seg-1||dx318412|x10354453|sx1|LOG: |00000|statement: SET DATESTYLE = "ISO"; Select * 
from bb 
where cc='1'||||||SET DATESTYLE = "ISO"; Select * from bb where cc='1'|0||postgres.c|1447|
2013-04-10 12:45:48.277080 EST|aa|tsi|p22814|th1093698336|172.30.0.186|3304|2013-04-10 12:44:29 AFT|10400046|con67|cmd5|seg-1||dx341|x10400046|sx1|LOG: |00000|statement: create table xx as (select r.xx,sum(r."XX"),c.dd from region_RR r, cat_CC c
where r.aa=c.vv
group by 1)||||||create table xx as (select r.xx,sum(r."XX"),c.dd from region_RR r, cat_CC c
where r.aa=c.vv
group by 1)
|0||postgres.c|1447|
```

is one record, which has many `\n` characters. And I need to parse with awk and get for example the 5th fields out of it.

Comment: I'm assuming you'll have multiple records per file? Could you provide a larger sample? I wouldn't use `awk` do to tackle this. Is there a particular reason for the `awk` constraint?

Comment: Like @MattH says please provide input with at least 2 record, they may be an inherent record separator such as a blank line?

Comment: Please post the expected output for the given input and confirm the input in question is formatted the same as your actual file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing inspiration from sudo_O's answer above...
Set a variable FIELD_TO_PRINT to the field position of interest and another variable FIELDS_PER_RECORD to the number of fields that represent a record. Tested with `GNU awk` on Ubuntu

```
awk   -v FIELDS_PER_RECORD=10 -v FIELD_TO_PRINT=5 'BEGIN{FS="|"; RS="\0"}\
{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if (i % FIELDS_PER_RECORD == FIELD_TO_PRINT) {print $i} }}' file_name.txt
th2056569632
x10354453
SET DATESTYLE = "ISO"; Select * from bb where cc='1'
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know `awk` could do that.

Comment: This input given by the OP is single record, they only want a single field per record, this gives 3 fields for the given record.

Comment: @sudo_O, it appeared to me that the OP's suggesting an implicit record length based on a fixed number of fields, so I coded an answer based off this assumption.

Comment: This is fine, I was just pointing out that `FIELDS_PER_RECORD` was not correct. For the OP case you want `FIELDS_PER_RECORD=29`.

Comment: It worked for me:[gpadmin@gpblade1 data]$ cat /tmp/aa.txt |  awk -v FIELDS_PER_RECORD=29 -v FIELD_TO_PRINT=5  ' BEGIN{FS="|"; RS="\0"}  {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if (i % FIELDS_PER_RECORD == FIELD_TO_PRINT) {print $i} }} '
th2056569632
th1093698336

Answer (score 1):

For just one record in a file you cant to set the record separator to the null character `RS='\0'` so the input file is read as one whole record:

```
$ awk '{print $5}' FS='|' RS='\0' file
th2056569632
```

For multiple records you could use the `date` as a record separator *(unless they're separated with a blank line already which would make things simpler or unless you need this field in the output)*:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $5}' FS='|' RS='(^|[^|])[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' file
th2056569632
th1093698336
```

---

Would the much simpler `grep -o 'th[0-9]*' file`  be suitable here?

Comment: I think the OP is implying that there may be multiple records

Comment: Unfortunetly it is not working on CentOS and Solaris as well.-bash-3.00$  awk 'NR>1{print $5}' FS='|' RS='(^|[^|])[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' /tmp/aa.txt



0
-bash-3.00$
CentOS:[gpadmin@gpblade1 data]$ awk 'NR>1{print $5}' FS='|' RS='(^|[^|])[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' /tmp/aa.txt
[gpadmin@gpblade1 data]$
I also attached file aa.txt

Comment: @martinnovoty `/usr/bin/awk` on Solaris is old/broken `awk` please use  `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead. Even better get the last version of `gawk` on your systems if you can.

Comment: -bash-3.00$  /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'NR>1{print $5}' FS='|' RS='(^|[^|])[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' /tmp/aa.txt



1447
-bash-3.00$

Comment: [gpadmin@gpblade1 data]$ gawk 'NR>1{print $5}' FS='|' RS='(^|[^|])[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' /tmp/aa.txt 
[gpadmin@gpblade1 data]$

Comment: @martinnovoty okay so you have thrown a bunch of unformatted code at me with no explanation. I have no clue what is in `/tmp/aa.txt`...

Comment: sorry, I could not load aa.txt here, as I tried, thank you for your help, but aa.txt caontains same text as in question (I copied myself from there )

Comment: @martinnovoty a side note, would the much simpler `grep -o 'th[0-9]*' file` be suitable?

Comment: :-)), ok, last note, I am actually trying to get SQL statements from log. Anyway thanks a lot. Sometimes I wonder how fast you respond. Look like some artificial intelligence in behind ..., thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, not what you've asked for: for the sake of comparison, here's how I might do it in python:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def records_from_file(f,separator='|',field_count=30):
  record = []
  for line in f:
    fields = line.split(separator)
    if len(record) > 0:
      # Merge last of existing with first of new
      record[-1] += fields[0]
      # Extend rest of fields
      record.extend(fields[1:])
    else:
      record.extend(fields)
    if len(record) > field_count:
      raise Exception("Concatenating records overflowed number of fields",record)
    elif len(record) == field_count:
      yield record
      record = []

sample = """2013-03-24 15:49:40.575175 EST|aaa|tsi|p1753|th2056569632|172.30.10.212|56809|2013-03-24 15:49:32 AFT|10354453|con2326|cmd7|seg-1||dx318412|x10354453|sx1|LOG: |00000|statement: SET DATESTYLE = "ISO"; Select * 
from bb 
where cc='1'||||||SET DATESTYLE = "ISO"; Select * from bb where cc='1'|0||postgres.c|1447|
2013-04-10 12:45:48.277080 EST|aa|tsi|p22814|th1093698336|172.30.0.186|3304|2013-04-10 12:44:29 AFT|10400046|con67|cmd5|seg-1||dx341|x10400046|sx1|LOG: |00000|statement: create table xx as (select r.xx,sum(r."XX"),c.dd from region_RR r, cat_CC c
where r.aa=c.vv
group by 1)||||||create table xx as (select r.xx,sum(r."XX"),c.dd from region_RR r, cat_CC c
where r.aa=c.vv
group by 1)
|0||postgres.c|1447|"""

for record in records_from_file(StringIO(sample)):
  print record[4]
```

Yielding:

```
th2056569632
th1093698336
```